# jspm: Error on Lookup - unexpected end of file at Zlib._handle.onerror

Tags: npm, jspm

I'm getting the error below when running `jspm install`.  Each time the error occurs on a different package dependency.  They do always seem to be npm packages.  Any ideas on this?

```
(local) me@mymachine:~/code/mineproject/static/js$ ~/bin/node/bin/jspm install

warn Running jspm globally, it is advisable to locally install jspm via npm install jspm --save-dev.
     Looking up npm:core-js
     Looking up npm:detect-browser
     Looking up npm:lodash
     Looking up npm:muicss
     Looking up npm:rc-collapse
     Looking up npm:react
     Looking up npm:react-accordion-component
     Looking up npm:react-animate
     Looking up npm:react-bootstrap-typeahead
     Looking up npm:react-collapse
     Looking up npm:react-collapsible
     Looking up npm:react-dom
     Looking up npm:react-height
     Looking up npm:react-motion
     Updating registry cache...
     Looking up github:oblador/react-native-collapsible
     Looking up npm:babel-runtime
     Looking up npm:babel-core
     Looking up npm:Faker
     Looking up npm:classnames
     Looking up npm:fbjs
     Looking up npm:highcharts
     Looking up npm:history
     Looking up npm:isomorphic-fetch
     Looking up npm:material-ui
     Looking up npm:mapbox.js
     Looking up npm:moment
     Looking up npm:moment-duration-format
     Looking up npm:newforms
     Looking up npm:pusher-js
     Looking up npm:normalizr
     Looking up npm:query-string
     Looking up npm:react-bootstrap
     Looking up npm:react-chartjs
     Looking up npm:msgpack-lite
     Looking up npm:raygun4js
     Looking up npm:react-mapboxmap
     Looking up npm:react-bootstrap-daterangepicker
     Looking up npm:react-highcharts
     Looking up npm:react-router
     Looking up npm:react-redux
     Looking up npm:react-scroll
     Looking up npm:react-s3-uploader
     Looking up npm:react-select
     Looking up npm:react-input-autosize
     Looking up npm:redux
     Looking up npm:redux-devtools
     Looking up npm:redux-devtools-dock-monitor
     Looking up npm:redux-devtools-log-monitor
     Looking up npm:redux-thunk
     Looking up npm:superagent
     Looking up npm:redux-simple-router
     Looking up github:floatdrop/plugin-jsx
     Looking up github:components/jquery

warn Error on lookup for npm:react-bootstrap, retrying (1).
     Error: read ECONNRESET

warn Error on lookup for npm:react-highcharts, retrying (1).
     Error: read ECONNRESET

warn Error on lookup for npm:Faker
     Error: unexpected end of file
         at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:370:17)

err  Error looking up npm:Faker.

warn Installation changes not saved.
```

Versions:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-77-generic x86_64)
- jspm: 0.16.47
- node: 6.9.1
- npm: 3.10.8

Comment: It looks like an issue was opened here:  https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/2149